# a roll id has 6 subjects, Now I always want to show set of 6 for each roll with or without respective values

Tags: sql, oracle

Say rolls 1,2,3,4,5

say subjects - chem,comp, hist, phys

but some have marks and some have null as marks .. Now I want to show as

```
roll   sub  marks
1      chem   64
1      comp   null
1      hist   55
1      phys   null
2      chem   null
2      comp   46
2      hist   55
2      phys   null
3      chem   null
3      comp   null
3      hist   55
3      phys   78
```

How can I achive this join .. if the tables are different
there is student table,subject table and marks table

Answer (score 0):

You may form a "calendar" table consisting of all rolls and subjects.  Then, left join this calendar table to your current table containing the actual marks:

```sql
SELECT
    r.roll,
    s.sub,
    t.marks
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT roll FROM yourTable) r
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT sub FROM yourTable) s
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON t.roll = r.roll AND t.sub = s.sub
ORDER BY
    r.roll,
    s.sub;
```

Note that if you have a long term requirement for this type of query, you ideally should keep on tap bona fide tables for the rolls and subjects.

Answer (score 0):

> if the tables are different there is student table, subject table and marks table

You use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the dat you want:

```
select su.*, st.*, m.mark
from students st cross join
     subjects su left join
     marks m
     on m.student_id = st.student_id and m.subject_id = su.subject_id
order by st.student_id, su.subject_id;
```